# Gmail API - Massive Requests

Tags: php, laravel, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I have a platform that get user's email and search for an attachment bringing it to platform and show to the users. But the users need to send it to a specific email and we search in this email the files of their emails. But now I want to make it "better" to them. Working automatically...

I have a database with many clients and now I want to provide a smart solution to them by:

- Get the files from their emails automatically and put all of them on the platform. (they will make an authentication using their email provider account(gmail))
- So it will be a lot of requests. Because I need search on their emails the exactly email that contains the file of the platform need.
- When the user "requests" an update, I will search only in the news emails, based on the last update date.

So to summarize:

- Use gmail authentication to get authorization to search for "specific files(.csv) in user's emails."
- Make a millions of requests(one request for each user to search this file on their emails) by day to Gmail API.
- Save those data on my server and after provide those data to the users in Android device.

I want to implement that, but I don't know if I need to register or make something before(such as special register on Google) to create this solution.

Comment: *Anything* is possible.

Comment: Can you help me with that? I saw the API but I don't have sure if I can do a lot of requests by the same server per day(millions of requests). Thank you!

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: I want to know if the API will allow me make millions of requests by day without getting Bad Many Requests from the server.

Comment: Have you asked the folks at GMail?

Comment: No, I haven't yet. I'm actually searching for a solution by this, if I don't find it in a few hours, I will ask there. Thank you anyway ;)

Comment: I suspect it's *extremely* unlikely Google will permit millions of API requests per day without substantial payment for that capacity.

Comment: if you are willing to pay for the extra queries over the free amount, you definitely can do that.

Comment: There's no problem if I need pay for that. I just would like to know if its possible do that by using google.

Comment: May you help me with a documentation or link where can I see about it? Thx!

Comment: Daily Usage:
1,000,000,000 quota units per day
Per User Rate Limit:
250 quota units per user per second, moving average (allows short bursts)

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Gmail Api provides pretty high amount of request for free.

> Daily Usage   **1,000,000,000 quota units per day**
>
> Per User Rate Limit   **250 quota units per user per second**

[Google Gmail Api Reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota)

I bet this amount can handle quite a lot.

And as you said, you might be pulling a lot of attachments, which every request of getting attachment, will cost you 5 quota unit. With this being provided, you can pull 200,000,000 attachments per day.

I think Gmail API is not "billable" as of now. But you probably can request more if the provided amount will not suffice your need.